# How do SQL order-by with multiple-columns work?

Tags: sql

I'm studying this SQL statement :

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY Country,CustomerName;
```

[From this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

How does it work that it orders by both country and CustomerName ? In my mind it just doesn't  seem intuitive, i.e you order by either Country  OR CustomerName but not both

Comment: it sorts first by Country and within Country, by CustomerName.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It orders by Country, but if some rows have the same Country, it orders them by CustomerName.

Comment: I other words, 2nd sort is applied on duplicated values or a an identical sub group of elements?

Answer (score 6):

It orders by country first. If the countries match, then it orders by customer name. It sorts the customers alphabetically but groups them by country, so English customers come before French ones.

Answer (score 3):

The select you pointed out, do the following

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY Country,CustomerName;
```

Select all the content of table Customers. With all the results, order by Country. When all the content has been order, then order the result by CustomerName.

This might look like this:

```
Country - CustomerName
Belgium   Dupont
Belgium   Fredrich
Bresil    Gregio
USA       John
```

=> Same country, ordered by name.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I have a data set like this one -

| id | name | age | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Bob | 56 | 68 |
| 1 | Alex | 23 | 75 |
| 6 | Don | 15 | 52 |
| 5 | Cass | 78 | 60 |
| 2 | Alex | 34 | 68 |
| 4 | Bob | 45 | 62 |

and I try to sort this using two columns namely - `name` in Ascending order and `age` in Descending Order

```sql
SELECT name, age, weight FROM table ORDER BY name, age DESC;
-- This will be my query
```

First it will sort it using `name` in ascending order and this would look like this

| id | name | age | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | 23 | 75 |
| 2 | Alex | 34 | 68 |
| 4 | Bob | 45 | 62 |
| 3 | Bob | 56 | 68 |
| 5 | Cass | 78 | 60 |
| 6 | Don | 15 | 52 |

But now when it will sort using `age` it will resolve the ties only, so here is what

| id | name | age | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Alex | 34 | 68 |
| 1 | Alex | 23 | 75 |
| 3 | Bob | 56 | 68 |
| 4 | Bob | 45 | 62 |
| 5 | Cass | 78 | 60 |
| 6 | Don | 15 | 52 |

Basically, it always sorts with the first column name in the `ORDER BY` clause, the rest is there to just there to resolve the ties, if there were two rows with same `name` and `age` values, the third column would have been used to resolve the ties of rows of having same `name` and `age`.